# Como descrever execução do laço for JavaScript em Português?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, loop, for

Sou iniciante em programação, e estou no módulo de instruções do curso ao qual estudo e me deparei com esse código abaixo na instrução dupla de `for`. Entendi em parte como essa instrução está funcionando (debugando), mas como poderia escrever no esboço dos meus estudos essa estrutura?

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  let linha = '';
  for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    linha += `[${i}, ${j}]`;
  }
  console.log(linha);
}
```

Comment: opa Luiz felipe ja estava editando mais vc editou ai pra mim, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenha em mente que o próprio código já é a descrição mais adequada que você pode ter.

---

Traduzindo este código, em JavaScript:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  let linha = '';
  for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    linha += `[${i}, ${j}]`;
  }
  console.log(linha);
}
```

Para uma das infinitas traduções em português, poderíamos fazer algo como:

- Enquanto <kbd>i</kbd> for menor ou igual a 3 (somando 1 à <kbd>i</kbd> após cada iteração), faça:

  - Declare <kbd>linha</kbd> como string vazia.
  - Enquanto <kbd>j</kbd> for menor ou igual a 3 (somando 1 à <kbd>j</kbd> após cada iteração), faça:

    - Atribuir à <kbd>linha</kbd> o resultado da concatenação das strings: `"["`, <kbd>i</kbd> (em string), `", "`, <kbd>j</kbd> (em string) e `"]"`.
  - Invoque a função <kbd>console.log</kbd> passando, como primeiro argumento, <kbd>linha</kbd>.

<sub><sub>É uma das infinitas possibilidades de tradução.</sub></sub>

---

Note que, embora o **funcionamento** tenha sido corretamente traduzido de JavaScript para uma estrutura em português, assumindo que só possuíssemos a versão em português do algoritmo, não conseguiríamos assumir, com certeza, a estrutura sintática do código original. Conseguiríamos apenas reproduzir a lógica do código.

Claro, levando a tradução ao pé da letra, poderíamos acabar utilizando um `for` e chegar em algo bem similar. Mas como, estritamente falando, a língua portuguesa não consegue expressar corretamente todas as estruturas sintáticas do JavaScript, poderíamos acabar escrevendo algo como:

```
let i = 1;
while (i <= 3) {
  let linha = '';
  let j = 1;
  while (j <= 3) {
    linha += '[' + i + ', ' + j + ']';
    j++;
  }
  console.log(linha);
  i++;
}
```

Ou, se seguíssemos somente o *funcionamento* do algoritmo expresso, poderíamos acabar chegando em algo mais diferente ainda.

---

Acabei indo além do que precisava, mas acho importante destacar esses pontos. Em suma, se a estrutura sintática do código não é importante, traduzi-lo para uma "linguagem humana" (como o português) pode ser uma opção razoável a depender da situação. No entanto, se essa estrutura for importante, escrever o código na linguagem original é a única opção que vejo como ideal.

A título de curiosidade, o padrão ECMAScript (a especificação que rege o JavaScript) não descreve os algoritmos dos *built-ins* da linguagem em JavaScript! É utilizada uma versão "inglesada" dos passos do algoritmo para que cada implementação possa montar o código que lhe convém, buscando, por exemplo, otimizações — que vão, na maioria das vezes, além do escopo de um padrão como esse.

Veja por exemplo a especificação do método `Array.prototype.forEach` na seção [§ 22.1.3.12](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach).

Comment: Explicação melhor que essa nao tem outra!!! Obrigado Luiz... abs